# 'No such file' when running rm AppleSetupDone from single-user mode

Tags: macos, administrator

I'm in High Sierra (10.13.6) and recently I renamed my account in Users & Group. Now I lost access to my administrator (so I can't install apps or change settings in System Preferences).

I already tried to solve my problem by following [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/164332/316431) but I can't make it past the

> ```
> rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
> ```

command, or maybe I'm doing something wrong there?

However, here's the single-user mode screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you searched on here? this is but one : https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328200/237687

Comment: On your screenshot, you entered the following command three times incorrectly (pay attention to every single character, including the space after "rm"): `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter the commands precisely, noting all spaces. If no message is shown, the command was successful, much like `/sbin/mount -uw /`. Enter precisely the following, followed by <kbd>⏎ Enter/Return</kbd>:

```
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

```
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

- With the first command, there's no need to keep re-running it, and no need to run it differently, it worked first try when you didn't receive an error.
- With the second command, all three tries missed the space between `rm` and `/var`. Make sure the space is typed.

You should not receive a message for either command and will be returned to the prompt (#) after each is executed. Finally, run `reboot`.

Comment: Thanks mate! i just realise it after i post it to this site. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I could just not find the `.AppleSetupDone` file anywhere it was supposed to be, and I was also a little confused about whether it would be on the `Macintosh HD - Data` volume or the `Macintosh HD` volume, so I eventually just decided to do a `find` command on all of the mounted volumes which worked great because it turned up under `Macintosh HD - Data/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` for some reason, not really sure why.

Anyway after I found it there the `rm` command worked fine.

So I guess if you've tried everything and you're still really not finding the `.AppleSetupDone` file you can check in the directory I mentioned or just run the find command from the root folder `/`

I did `find . -iname "*setupdone*"`