# Revert Home directory location with CLI after changing with system preferences by

Tags: macos, terminal, recovery, login

My late 2019 iMac was running out of disk space and since all the upgrade kits seem to be out of stock (and the upgrade process difficult) I decided to try moving my home directory to an external thunderbolt SSD as per the instructions here https://www.lifewire.com/move-macs-home-folder-new-location-2260157

Whether a result of encryption (external SSD is encrypted APFS with the password stored in my users keychain), or a slow mount, I’m no longer able to login to my computer which simply states ‘unable to login an error has occurred’

I’ve tried using single user mode and disabling various security features to mount the drive to no avail which always results in ‘permission denied’ as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388479

What I’ve been able to do is boot into recovery mode and mount the ‘Macintosh HD - Data’ drive through disk utility.

I can see my home directory is still on this internal drive and is writeable and think if I can just change the setting back manually I should be able to login.

Does anyone know where this setting is located so I can simply edit it through the command line?

(Example screenshot from Apple discussion)
[image: Screenshot from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6084975]

Max OS Monterey 12.?
27” iMac 2019
FileVault enabled on local ssd
APFS encryption on external thunderbolt SSD

Comment: Try this: `dscl . -read Users/bb NFSHomeDirectory` should print the current value, and with `dscl . -change Users/demouser NFSHomeDirectory oldValue /Users/bb` you might be able so reset it to the default.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, unfortunately this returns “Cannot open remote host, error: DSOpenDirServiceErr”

Comment: My mistake I missed the . But now it returns DS Error -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)

Comment: I know that user information is stored in the “directory services” and that can be accessed with the `dscl` tool. But to be honest, I do *not* know what exactly is possible in the single-user mode. Does `dscl . -list Users` show your account? What about `dscl . -read Users/yourUserName` ?

Comment: I’m also wondering if dscl queries a differnt set of logins when in recovery mode? ‘dscl . -ls Users’ shows a long list of users but not my username at all

Comment: You could also try to recover the admin account, compare https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/164331/30895.

Comment: @MartinR thank you - I initially thought about the admin account recovery but couldn't find the `/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` file - I realize now the actual path is `/Macintosh HD - Data/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone` as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347816/no-such-file-when-running-rm-applesetupdone-from-single-user-mode. FYI - now that I am logged in again to the actual system, `dscl . -list Users` does show the users so I think single user mode is indeed querying a different directory system. Thank you for the help.