# How can I completely change an account name, including the record name?

Tags: user-account

Even when I option click the user for advanced settings, change the name, account name, and the home directory to match, when I open the terminal, the old name still shows as `oldname@Macbook-Air ~ %`. When I view the account in Directory Utility, there is a Record Name field as well as a dozen or so others which still hav the old name. When I change this, the password no longer works. How can I completely purge the old name?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in https://support.apple.com/hr-hr/HT201548 and log out and back in again?

Comment: Warning: it's easy to [lock yourself out of admin access this way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328192/lost-access-to-admin-user-account-in-my-mac-book-pro); I'd recommend creating a spare backup admin account so you won't lose control of the Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a new account using the new name, transfer what you need from the old account, then delete the old account?