# How to regain admin privileges on Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur, recovery, administrator

I'm using Big Sur and renamed my admin account. Now it has been downgraded to a standard account. There are other admin accounts on the system, so backing everything up and reinstalling wouldn't work. I can't use single user mode because that doesn't exist anymore. [Removing `.AppleSetupDone`, for some weird reason, does not work either.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328200/5472)

How else should I try to regain my admin privileges?

Comment: If you have other admin accounts, why not re-add admin rights from one of those?

Comment: Those aren't mine.

Comment: Why can‘t you just ask one of the other users then?

Comment: They're not nearby.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the absent admin get back to you sooner than you [decide to wipe the Mac and start over](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212190).

In the mean time, you can try the normal “forgot” steps in case you remember or have access to any alternate unlock methods to override an admin account.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860

My hunch is you’re trying to remove a non-existent .AppleSetupDone file from the data volume and didn’t realize or accommodate for the [Big Sur system volume being immutable / sealed](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/30/is-big-surs-system-volume-sealed/).

Answer (score -2):

A possible solution is to boot from a recovery drive (like a USB stick), using any UN*X system (Linux, MacOS, *BSD, etc). However, I recommend a MacOS installer if your drive is encrypted by FileVault.

So after you have gained have full access to the drive (eh, you are root :), you just have to create a new user account with full privileges.

However, be careful: this is not a trivial thing to do, and you better have a sysadmin at hand for helping you through it.

Comment: Just to confirm, this won't mess with any accounts, right?

Comment: Absolutely: this does create a new user account, with admin privileges. Your account and files are not modified.